# leafletjs marker bindpopup() with options

Tags: popup, leaflet, marker

The leaflet documention shows you can add a popup to a marker with

```
marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.").openPopup();
```

or create a standalone popup with

```
var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng([51.5, -0.09])
    .setContent("I am a standalone popup.")
    .openOn(map);
```

Is there no way to set popup options and bind it to a marker? I want to be able to set my own maxwidth for popups and have them open/close when you click a marker.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you sure that you're reading the [Leaflet reference documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-bindpopup)? It specifies that you can bind a popup with options by creating it and calling .bindPopup with it. For instance,

```
var popup = L.popup()
    .setContent("I am a standalone popup.");

marker.bindPopup(popup).openPopup();
```

Comment: Ok, then that means, that you always have to create the popup first and then bind it to the marker. :-(

Comment: Well, this one-liner is possible: `var mark1=L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).bindPopup(L.popup({maxWidth:500}).setContent("I am a standalone popup.")).addTo(map);`

Comment: And to set a fixed width for your popups, add to your styles: `.leaflet-popup-content { width:500px; }`

Answer (score 11):

You can pass an object of [popup options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#popup-option) as the second argument of bindPopup, like this:

```
marker.bindPopup("<strong>Hello world!</strong><br />I am a popup.", {maxWidth: 500});
```

I've tested this in Leaflet 1.4, and it also seems be available in earlier versions of [bindPopup](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layer-popup-methods).

Comment: I'd say this is what the OP (and I) was looking for.

Comment: bravo Richard, great find

Answer (score 6):

For maxWidth you should do this:

```
var popup = L.popup({
    maxWidth:400
});
marker.bindPopup(popup).openPopup();
```